# Months between 2 dates

Tags: formula-field

I am trying to get the number of months between 2 dates(01'Aug 19 and Today).

I am using the below formula, but am geting a syntax error

```
(((YEAR(TODAY()) - YEAR(2019,08,01) - 1) *12) + (12 - MONTH(2019,08,01) +1) + MONTH(TODAY()))
```

Error: Incorrect number of parameters for function 'YEAR()'. Expected 1, received 3

I checked YEAR accepts 3 parameters, then why is it complaining that It expects 1?

I am new to the forum and to SF, so please excuse mistakes in my post.
Thanks

Comment: Hi and welcome to SFSE. The community may provide some answer to this question but I would recommend you read [How to Ask](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and consider [updating](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/285616/edit) your question with detail about what you have already tried for yourself and where you are stuck. The point to note is that this isn't a coding service and that you should have demonstrated your efforts so far.

Comment: You're probably looking at the wrong documentation.  In formula fields, both `MONTH` and `YEAR` accept only one parameter.  See [formula documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customize_functions_i_z.htm&type=5)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `YEAR()` function only accepts one parameter, that is being the date. So instead of using `YEAR(2019,08,01)`, you should first create a `DATE()` and then take the year out of it. For example:

```
YEAR(DATE(2019,08,01))
```

Which does not make any sense if you are hardcoding the date, instead you can just use `2019` instead.

Comment: Thanks so much. The code now compiled.